# Roots of polynomials with integer coefficients

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $N\in\mathbb{N}$ be sufficiently large and $n$ is even. I am trying to prove (or disprove) that if $M_0,M_1,\dots,M_n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $M_n>M_i$ for $i=0,1,2,...,n-1$, then the polynomial

$$P(z) = z^{n+1}-NM_nz^n+NM_{n-1}z^{n-1}-NM_{n-2}z^{n-2}+\cdots-NM_0$$ has a positive root greater than 1. By Descartes' rule of sign, $P$ has a positive root but I can't show that a root is more than 1. I tried using the fact that $NM_n$ is the sum of the roots but I am still stuck.

Comment: This isn’t really well-defined unless you specify how sufficiently large $N$ is. Or are you looking for an $N$ that makes your claim true?

Comment: It means the claim if true for $N>N_0$ for some $N_0\in\mathbb{N}$. $N_0$ may depend on $M_0,...,M_n$ and n.

Comment: Then your quantifiers are out of order, you need to start with “if $M_i...$ then there is an $N_0$ such that...”. Right now it looks like you want such a bound that works uniformly for all choices of the Ms.

Comment: Part 1: what is the value of the polynomial when $x=1 \; ? \; $ Part 2: where did you get the problem?

Comment: seems also the constant term should be $-NM_0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem right (given $M_k$ there is $N_0$ st the respective polynomial has a root greater than $1$ for $N >N_0$) the only thing one needs is that $M_n >0$ since then letting

$g(z)=M_nz^n-M_{n-1}z^{n-1}+...+M_0$

there is $r>1, g(r)=a>0$ ($g(x) \to \infty, x \to \infty, x >0)$ so for $N > \frac{r^{n+1}}{a}$ we have $P_N(r)=r^{n+1}-Ng(r) <0$ so there is a positive root greater than $r>1$ as $P_N(x) \to \infty, x \to \infty, x>0$

Comment: Got it. Thanks.